# Check if Childs have specific value

Tags: swift, dictionary, firebase

When a user decides to delete his account I want to delete everything posted by the user.

So I want to go through the database and delete everything which contains his userId.

```
  let userId = API.User.CURRENT_USER?.uid

    API.Post.REF_POST.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (Post) in

        if let dict = Post.value as? [String: Any] {
            print("dict", dict)


        let uid = dict["uid"] as? String

            print(uid)
            print(userId)

            if uid == userId {
                print("gefunden")
            }else {
                print("nichts")
            }

        }
    }
```

This prints out nil as uid.
I still get all the post data printed out.

```
"posts" : {
"-Kt1h76YbyIqmSRkkLsv" : {
  "bookmarkCount" : 0,
  "caption" : "Helm ",
  "characterCount" : 5,
  "commentCount" : 0,
  "creationDate" : 1.504357677437253E9,
  "likeCount" : 0,
  "photoUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/funcloud-8e84e.appspot.com/o/Posts%2F2B9606C8-E28D-4F69-9956-036192D36948?alt=media&token=2cd8712b-ca18-44a9-aa1d-d42e179a8eb7",
  "ratio" : 1.5056179775280898,
  "score" : -24,
  "uid" : "hUhEPEg99HMkas6CqMXE4ZIyu472"
},
"-Kt1msnhcK4sxGKi5cae" : {
  "bookmarkCount" : 0,
  "caption" : "",
  "characterCount" : 0,
  "commentCount" : 0,
  "creationDate" : 1.50435918759132E9,
  "likeCount" : 0,
  "photoUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/funcloud-8e84e.appspot.com/o/Posts%2F5E96D809-AF10-4FD7-B18A-4D138DDD4878?alt=media&token=16b9452b-25da-4f7b-9d93-80e557c91490",
  "ratio" : 0.75,
  "score" : 0,
  "uid" : "hUhEPEg99HMkas6CqMXE4ZIyu472"
}
},
```

When currentUserId equals the id of a post, which means it has been posted by exactly that user, I want to delete the entire Post.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your Database structure, I think, is wrong. Firebase suggest to use a flat representation of data

Try to add a new node under User which contains the ID of posts send by him.

```
user : {
    userId : {
      /* user data */
      posts: {
         postId1: true // the value isn't important
         postIdX: true  
      }
    }
    name : username
}

posts : {
    postId1: {
        /*post data*/
    }
}
```

Now you need to iterate over the posts dictionary which you know the url:

```
child("user/\(userId)/posts")
```

And for every key recovered you can call the removeValue() method which will remove all data contains under:

```
for (key, _) in dictionary {
    Database.database().child("posts/(key)").removeValue()
}
```

Hope this help you ;)

Comment: I only want to delete user relating stuff and not everything. So it is important to know if the value really exists.

Comment: Sorry, I have fix my answer

Comment: Thanks you, but still, how can I check if a child has a specific value?

Comment: You are welcome @Zash__ 
what you mean with "specific value"?

Comment: I still want to learn how I can check all Childs in my database ( eg. database.database().refrence.child("posts") ) if one of them contains a specific value, e.g. the uid of the user?

Comment: So I think you need to do some query over your db. Have you checked this https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data ?

Comment: I have answered my question now, please look through it and accept it if done correctly.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use cloud functions to remove all data.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/

Here, you can read more about it.
If the cloud function manages this process, you do not hav to worry about that waht happens if the remove fails somehow, bad network connection etc.

Comment: And how can I check if a value exists in a child?

Comment: I have to really get through this as I am a beginner to coding, this is not written in swift so it might take some time for me.

Comment: Yes, it will take some time, but learning to code is not a fast process.

Comment: I have to Write this in Java? I have no clue about java lol. Maybe this is too early then

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found it out now. Following is the code how you can iterate through the database and look if a child contains the value, in my example the userId.

```
let userId = API.User.CURRENT_USER?.uid

    API.Post.REF_POST.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in

        let arraySnapshot = (snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot])
// This is in order to take every single child into Account.
        arraySnapshot.forEach({ (child) in
            if let dict = child.value as? [String: Any] {
                let uid = dict["uid"] as? String
                //now I check every single child whether it contains the userId or now
                                if uid == userId {
                                    print("gefunden")
                                    Database.database().reference().child("posts").child(child.key).removeValue()
// I case the child contains the userId, I delete it. The child.key is the randomly created id of the child in which I am currently checking for the value.
                                } else {
                                    print("nichts")
                                }
            }
        })
    }
```

My problem before was that I just printed out the entire database, now I look up for each child in my Database, if it contains the value "uid" of my User who is about to delete his account.

Comment: What happens if the app crashes during the process?